# Regex on numbers - python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am new to regex and I need some help please. I have a dataframe in which I got column with amount, which is in most cases something like 869,850.0 and I need only rows where the number is ending with 950.00 or 999.00 I dont need something like 999.1 . I did not came up with any idea how to filer these values in pandas.

So I am trying to apply match with regex and because I am new to this I only know how to get number unit .  something like [^.]*. but I dont know how to apply if and how to continue, can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: Try this: ^[0-9]+(\.0+)?$     
I am considering that numbers without decimals are also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) instead of regex. It will give you the remainder after division, which can be used to get the "tail" of a number if a power of 10 is given. This tail can be checked with your conditions.

In your case the remainder of dividing by 1000 gives you the remainder you are looking for, see below example:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    1950., 
    1012950., 
    2999., 
    1950.1, 
])

s % 1000

# Returns 
# 950.
# 950.
# 999.
# 950.1

(s % 1000).isin([999., 950.])  # allowed values

# Returns
# True
# True
# True
# False

s[(s % 1000).isin([999., 950.])]

# Returns
# 1950.
# 1012950.
# 2999.

# Not: 1950.1, because 950.1 is not in [999., 950.]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex try the following:

```
[0-9]{3}\.0{2}
```

It will first match 3 numbers then match the dot(.) and then match 2 0. I hope this regex is easy enough to understand and tweak.

You can try the regex out here:

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
     df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['850890.0', '850999.0', '850990.0', '850995.0']})
     print(df)
               a
     0  850890.0
     1  850999.0
     2  850990.0
     3  850950.0

     #create a regex to find all numbers
     numbers = ['999.0', '950.0']

     #now put these values in a pattern
     pattern =  r'(?:{})'.format('|'.join(numbers))
     pattern
     '(?:999.0|950.0)'

     dfnew = df['a'].str.findall(pattern).apply(''.join,1)
     print(dfnew)
     0         
     1    999.0     
     2    
     3    950.0
     Name: a, dtype: object
```